# Is possible to determine the water flow rate of this pipe with only geometric informations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

[image]

We have this water tank ($R$) that is pumping water to the end of pipe ($E$) in this figure.

When I say geometric information I mean things like: area of the pipe section, height of the reservatory relative to the ground or other things like that. Can we determine the water flow rate that $E$ has in this project? How?

PS: Only measurable infomations needs to be geometric, constants can be used(like theb water density can be used.)

Comment: Even in the case of a ideally non-viscous fluid, you need to know the fluid density.

Comment: I think i restricted too much in "only geometric information",  i should have say "the information that need to be measure only can be geometric", so, constants should be allowed.